# how to access values in jquery muiltiselect through php

Tags: php, sql-update, kendo-multiselect

I'm using jquery multiselect and in options i'm fetching data from database these are basically available seats in a buss.. when user selected some seats and press the button i'm putting values on $_POST and using update query updating selected seats as reserved please help here is the code

** HTML SELECT tag with jquery and php for fetching data this is working fine **

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label for="required">Required</label>
    <select id="required" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select attendees..." name="required">
     <?php 

$con =   mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$link =      mysql_select_db("bus") or die(mysql_error());

     $query = " select seats.seatNo from seats where seats.isactive = 0 and seats.busID = 1";
     $result = mysql_query($query);
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $seatNo = $row['seatNo'];
         ?>

     <option> <?php echo $seatNo ?> </option>

     <?php } ?>

    </select>
```

And then I'm getting selected seats here and updating the db

```
<?php

$con;
$link;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
for($i = 0; $i<5; $i++)
{
$selected = $_POST['required'];
}
$insert = " update seats set seats.isactive = 1 where seats.seatNo = $selected and      seats.busID = 1";
$q = mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

if($q)
{
echo " record updated ";    
}

else
{
echo " couldn't update ";   
}

} 



?>
```

Comment: What's that `for` loop supposed to do?

Comment: The update query it is working but only last selected value is updating instead of all selected values

for eg : user reserve seatNo 1,2,3 and 4
only seatNo 4 updates as reserved instead of all four seats..

Comment: @jeroen I'm not good in php i used for loop that maybe $selected variable gets first 5 selected value and update them in db

Comment: You should do a `var_dump($_POST['required']);` to see what it contains exactly.

Comment: @jeroen it is containing the last selected value!

Comment: @jeroen 
let me tell you the scenario
users sees the available seats in bus in multiselect he select seats he wants now i want that the seatsNO user select get update into database as reserved as my db table structure is 

seatID, SeatNo, isActive(with bit datatype)
When user select some seatNo isActive bit boolean type updates as true this is want using update query 
But only last select value is updating as true in db 

like he selected SeatNO 1,2,3 and 4 only seatNo 4 will be updated as true in db